# Split a common Parent/Child column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    [PKey]  VARCHAR(10)
  , [CKey]  VARCHAR(10)
  , [GCKey] VARCHAR(10)
  , [CODE]  VARCHAR(10)
) ;

INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT 'A','','','A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','AB1','','AAB1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','AB2','','AAB2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','AB2','AB2C1','AAB2C1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','AB3','','AAB3'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','AB3','AB3C1','AAB3C1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A','AB3','AB3C2','AAB3C2'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B','','','B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B','BB1','','BBB1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C','','','C'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C','CB1','','CCB1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C','CB1','CB1C1','CCB1C1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'D','','','D_N/A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E','','','E'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'E','EB0','','EEB01'
```

Source data:

```
SELECT * FROM @Table ;

PKey    CKey    GCKey   CODE
A                       A
A       AB1             AAB1
A       AB2             AAB2
A       AB2     AB2C1   AAB2C1
A       AB3             AAB3
A       AB3     AB3C1   AAB3C1
A       AB3     AB3C2   AAB3C2
B                       B
B       BB1             BBB1
C                       C
C       CB1             CCB1
C       CB1     CB1C1   CCB1C1
D                       D_N/A
E                       E
E       EB0             EEB01
```

Goal: Hierarchy (there are only 3 levels) is [PKey] (Parent Key) > [CKey] (Child Key) > [GCKey] (GrandChild Key). [CODE] is the value that I'm trying to split into 3 different fields ([PCode], [CCode], and [GCCode]). I want to fill each parent field where there's a value with its Code value.

Is there a way to do this without multiple self joins?

Expected outcome:

```
PKey    CKey    GCKey   PCode   CCode   GCCode
A                       A       
A       AB1             A       AAB1    
A       AB2             A       AAB2    
A       AB2     AB2C1   A       AAB2    AAB2C1
A       AB3             A       AAB3    
A       AB3     AB3C1   A       AAB3    AAB3C1
A       AB3     AB3C2   A       AAB3    AAB3C2
B                       B       
B       BB1             B       BBB1    
C                       C       
C       CB1             C       CCB1    
C       CB1     CB1C1   C       CCB1    CCB1C1
D                       D_N/A       
E                       E       
E       EB0             E       EEB01
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT      [T1].[PKey]
          , [T1].[CKey]
          , [T1].[GCKey]
          , [T1].[CODE] AS [PCode]
          , COALESCE ( [T2].[CODE], '' ) AS [CCode]
          , COALESCE ( [T3].[CODE], '' ) AS [GCCode]
FROM        @Table AS [T1]
LEFT JOIN   @Table AS [T2]
ON          [T2].[PKey] = [T1].[PKey]
            AND [T2].[CKey] = [T1].[CKey]
            AND [T2].[CKey] <> ''
            AND [T2].[GCKey] = ''
LEFT JOIN   @Table AS [T3]
ON          [T3].[PKey] = [T1].[PKey]
            AND [T3].[CKey] = [T1].[CKey]
            AND [T3].[GCKey] <> ''
            AND [T3].[GCKey] = [T1].[GCKey] ;
```

Current outcome (notice PCode isn't correct):

```
PKey    CKey    GCKey   PCode   CCode   GCCode
A                       A       
A       AB1             AAB1    AAB1    
A       AB2             AAB2    AAB2    
A       AB2     AB2C1   AAB2C1  AAB2    AAB2C1
A       AB3             AAB3    AAB3    
A       AB3     AB3C1   AAB3C1  AAB3    AAB3C1
A       AB3     AB3C2   AAB3C2  AAB3    AAB3C2
B                       B       
B       BB1             BBB1    BBB1    
C                       C       
C       CB1             CCB1    CCB1    
C       CB1     CB1C1   CCB1C1  CCB1    CCB1C1
D                       D_N/A       
E                       E       
E       EB0             EEB01   EEB01
```

Comment: The OP did just fine with the images.  He also has actual test data creation code that actually works without modification.  Let's give this OP some thumbs-up!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all the joins.  Most of the work is already done for you in the 1st 4 columns.  You just need to concatenate some things with a little knowledge that "anything" + NULL = NULL.

Here's a coded solution using your good test data...

```
 SELECT  PKey
        ,CKey
        ,GCKey
        ,PCode  = PKey
        ,CCode  = ISNULL(PKey+NULLIF(CKey ,''),'')
        ,GCCODE = ISNULL(PKey+NULLIF(GCKey,''),'')
  FROM @Table
;
```

... and here are the results from that code.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately, I can't rely on the concatenation of PK/CK/GCK because there's a chance CODE could have some strange values. :(

Comment: I could add another left join for just PKey group - similar to CKey and GCKey - but that results in yet another self-join..

Comment: So, post some of those "strange" values along with what you expect and let's see what we can do about things.  Without an actual question, there can be no answer. :)

Comment: @Dale K - Thanks for the spelling correction.